# How to get login info from request.env?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apartment-gem

I am using rails as a back end API for a SaaS project. I want to use the generic elevator of the Apartment gem. I dont use devise or warden, simple User model. How do i get info from request.env to find the tenant name in the User model.

Comment: how are you passing the tenant name to the API?

Comment: I am passing it in the login form: email, company, and password. Company is the tenant name.